Question about electromagnetic induction
I have a question about electromagnetic induction and how it works when a magnet is moved towards a conductor. Here’s the setup:
Imagine a magnet held horizontally with the north pole facing to the right.
There’s a straight wire held vertically, so the wire is perpendicular to the magnetic field lines produced by the magnet.
The magnet is moved closer to the wire.
My questions are:
When the magnet gets closer to the wire, which direction does the induced current flow? Does it flow upward or downward along the wire?
They say an EMF is induced because of lorentz force but from the electrons' perspective, they are moving towards the magnet, and their velocity is parallel to the magnetic field. If that's the case, why would a force be acting on the electrons to cause them to move?
F= qVBsin0
F= 0N
No force= no current or correct me if I am wrong

Your question is close to a homework like question. You cold be more precise in your question. The abreviation "EMF" is not standard in physics. Do you mean an electromagnetic field?

@LukasNullmeier He means "emf" or "electromotive force". A potential difference.

@LukasNullmeier EMF is standard abbreviation in physics English for electromotive force.

@agaminon EMF is integral of impressed force per unit charge along a given path, it is not potential difference. Only in perfect conductor, EMF has the same magnitude as potential difference (but they act in opposite directions and cancel each other).

Induced EMF is due to induced electric field of the magnet. When magnet moves, it produces not only magnetic field, but also electric field.

The direction of current would be such as to generate a magnetic field that opposes the original one. In the case of a straight wire, this would probably be some strange current configuration, simply because under the geometry you propose a simple current up or down would generate an azimuthal field that would not directly oppose the magnetic field.
It's easier to see with a circular spire, with a magnet that you can move in and out. As you move the magnet into the coil, the right hand rule tells you that the current has to be generated clockwise so that the magnetic field generated points downwards as much as possible.

Just to answer your second question, since @agaminon aswered the first.

They say an EMF is induced because of lorentz force

That's not true. The emf is induced as a consequence of Faraday's law, which is a separate law from Lorentz force law. There is no meaning to say that Faraday's law is caused by Lorentz force, since the first could be observed in absence of charges, but the second could not. They are considered separate laws, and there is no gain to think about them with any causal relation.
What could be said, however, is that when we talk about Galilean transformations, in the laboratory reference frame the field are static and the charges are moving and Maxwell equations are not invariant by Galilean transformations, which means that if we insist in Galilean relativity, the explanation would come from another law, in this case the Lorentz force law.
Look that it causes confusion, and in fact it was one of the motivations for Einstein to develop the special relativity theory. In his article On the electrodynamics of the moving bodies , after showing how EM fields transform under Lorentz transformations, he compares the old and new way to explain the movement of moving charges in a EM field:
Old manner of expression

If a unit electric point charge is in motion in an electromagnetic field,
there acts upon it, in addition to the electric force, an “electromotive force”
which, if we neglect the terms multiplied by the second and higher powers of
v/c, is equal to the vector-product of the velocity of the charge and the magnetic
force, divided by the velocity of light.

New way of expression

If a unit electric point charge is in motion in an electromagnetic field,
the force acting upon it is equal to the electric force which is present at the
locality of the charge, and which we ascertain by transformation of the field to
a system of co-ordinates at rest relatively to the electrical charge. (New manner
of expression.)

And then he concludes

The analogy holds with “magnetomotive forces.” We see that electromotive
force plays in the developed theory merely the part of an auxiliary concept[...]

So, we should analyse the problem in the reference frame of the charge, where the magnetic field $\vec B$ is varying and producing an induced electric field $\vec E$. This electric field is responsible for the force $\vec F_{el}$ that old times was described as emf. If we insist to change the reference frame, we should transform the fields accordingly to Lorentz transformations, which could keep the EM invariant.
